# Rails 4: Double request/response/select/insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

in my rails 4 app I noticed, that when I create new comment, every request/response are doubles. anybody know why?
I'm using ajax
this is my logs:

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-25 21:07:06 +0400
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-25 21:07:06 +0400
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "recipe_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"llkl;kl;k;l", "commit"=>"Add Comment"}
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "recipe_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"llkl;kl;k;l", "commit"=>"Add Comment"}
Recipe Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Recipe Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("commentable_id", "commentable_type", "comment", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["commentable_id", 1], ["commentable_type", "Recipe"], ["comment", "llkl;kl;k;l"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-03-25 17:07:06.221648"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-25 17:07:06.221648"]]
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("commentable_id", "commentable_type", "comment", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["commentable_id", 1], ["commentable_type", "Recipe"], ["comment", "llkl;kl;k;l"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-03-25 17:07:06.221648"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-25 17:07:06.221648"]]
(17.8ms)  commit transaction
(17.8ms)  commit transaction
Comment Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = ? AND "comments"."commentable_type" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0  [["commentable_id", 1], ["commentable_type", "Recipe"]]
Comment Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = ? AND "comments"."commentable_type" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0  [["commentable_id", 1], ["commentable_type", "Recipe"]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Rendered recipes/_comments.html.erb (6.2ms)
Rendered recipes/_comments.html.erb (6.2ms)
Rendered comments/create.js.erb (15.3ms)
Rendered comments/create.js.erb (15.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 16.4ms | ActiveRecord: 20.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 16.4ms | ActiveRecord: 20.3ms)
```

Comment: Seems like your custom logger is configured incorrectly. Check it.

Comment: I didn't changed any logging configuration. but after adding new comment in show page I see every comment as doubled, but after refresh the page, everything is OK